# Using a date in a cell in Sheet1 as a value for a filter in a Countifs formula for values in the date range on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to use a formula in Google Sheets to use the date values of cells in Sheet1 (a27 and b27) as the Date references for the date range in the coutifs formula below.

=countifs('Sheet2'!$C:$C,">=01/10/2023", 'Sheet2'!$C:$C,"<=01/17/2023",'Sheet2'!$D:$D,"Apples")

This initial formula works fine, where I am trying to count how many instances of "apples" occurred in a specific date range on Sheet 2 (1/10/2023-1/17/2023).
As you can see, the dates on Sheet 2 are in column C, and the instance of "Apples" would be in column D.

However, I am trying to find a way to pull the data from Sheet2 to Sheet1 using date references in 2 cells in Sheet1. 'Sheet1'!a27 has the date value for 1/10/2023, and 'Sheet1'!b27 has the value for 1/17/2023.
I would like to be able to use the Sheet1 a27/b27 placeholders instead of manually going in and entering dates into the formula.

I have tried the string below, hoping it would pull the date values from Sheet1 a27&b27 automatically to be the date of reference for the countifs formula from Sheet2.

While it is not causing an "error", it is not pulling any numbers at all.

=countifs('Sheet2'!$C:$C,">='Sheet1'!a27", 'Sheet2'!$C:$C,"<='Sheet1'!b27",'Sheet2'!$D:$D,"Apples")

Please note that Sheet2 column C and Sheet1 columns b&c already have the number formats set to "date".

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!C:C, ">="&Sheet1!A27, 
          Sheet2!C:C, "<="&Sheet1!B27, Sheet2!D:D, "Apples")
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this.

It's giving me an 
"Error:
Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size."

I wonder if it's not possible on google sheets?

Comment: @JasminKappert can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Comment: I've drafted up a sample here. Thanks for your help! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19BkorFpsb0WiCHuw6wJ_aDmPToIkNwWV1H_rMIsCDIU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JasminKappert here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LXT_52KK3RRLl7tJMj5iRAHtouG_PFpF8rvC8UVBKLM/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems to be working now! You saved me a lot of headache in my entire 20+tab spreadsheet haha